# Play 2.6 with Java - Adding Environment Dependency Injection

Tags: java, playframework

I need to use the Play.Environment in one of my java class as below. I am using Play 2.6.x. Can you please help me in understanding, how to add dependency injection here. I tried using as below, but the env object is coming as NULL.

MyFile.java

```
public final class MyFinalClass  {

 @Inject
 static Environment env;

public static String getFilePath(String fileName)  {
        return env.rootPath().getAbsolutePath();
}
static {
//It has a static block and some code here. I dont have any constructor.
}
}
```

Thanks

/***************************************************************************/
I have modified the above code and make it Singleton as below:

```
MyFinalClass.java
public class MyFinalClass   implements IConfigurationManager {

    @Inject Environment env;
    private static MyFinalClass   INSTANCE;

    //Pvt Constructor
    private MyFinalClass  () {

    }

    //Create Singleton Instance
    public static MyFinalClass instance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new MyFinalClass();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

//Module.java
class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure( {

        bind(MyFinalClass.class).asEagerSingleton();
      }
```

Here I am getting Error as :  **Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.**

Then I modified as below:

```
Environment env;
//Pvt Constructor
@Inject private MyFinalClass  (Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}
```

Here I am getting compilation issue the new MyFinalClass expects argument. 
Can you please help in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Static field injection is [not recommended](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections). If you really need to have your class and method static you should use Guice's [requestStaticInjection(..)](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection-java.lang.Class...-).
You could also make MyFinalClass a Singleton, inject Environment in the constructor and then inject MyFinalClass wherever you need to use getFilePath(..).

**Edit**: I see your comment about requestStaticInjection, so here is a short description about how to use it. Honestly I think it's more tidy to just make the class a Singleton. If you have stuff in MyFinalClass that you don't want to include in a Singleton maybe you should create a new class.

To use requestStaticInjection() you have to do the request from a module, and this module needs to be [loaded](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaPlayModules).

```
public class InjectorModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        requestStaticInjection(MyFinalClass.class);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**:
You have changed your question now to use Singleton, but you are doing it wrong.
Check the [Play Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Singletons), you just have to add the @Singleton annotation to your class.

Example where we create a singleton and a controller class that injects it (I'm writing this directly in the editor, not tested code but you get the idea):

```
@Singleton
public class MyFinalClass {
    private Environment env;

    @Inject
    public MyFinalClass(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public String getFilePath(String fileName) {
        return env.rootPath().getAbsolutePath();
    }
}

public class TestController extends Controller {
    @Inject
    private MyFinalClass myFinalClass;

    public Result index() {
        String fileName = "test.tst";
        String filePath = myFinalClass.getFilePath(fileName);

        return ok(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , I tried using the requestStaticInjection() as below: but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer to include an example of requestStaticInjection usage, please take a look.

Comment: HI, As you suggested I created a Singleton class and trying to inject. I have modified the question above. Can you please help

Comment: Hie, I have added another example in my post.

Comment: Hi Eirik, Thanks a lot for responding, really appreciate. Now I have a couple of query, please excuse me if its basic.  In my project many of the Singleton class is written as i mentioned the code above. @Singleton is not used anywhere and its the normal way of making constructor private. Then there are a lot of place from where its called as className.instance().method(). Now if I use @ Singleton, then do I need to inject the Singleton class object to each class where I am using it. And other question is, the constructor is public in your example, will not it make any issue for singleton.

Comment: Also the above code I mentioned, I am able to resolve using requestStaticInjection. Then do I need to use @Singleton. I am afraid if I use , i may have to inject the singleton object many places in the code.

Comment: When creating a singleton with the @Singleton annotation you are doing it the Play/Guice way. If not (like your code above) you are doing it the "old"/regular Java way.

Comment: You may still create your constructor private, that's not a problem, I just wrote a quick example in the editor.
And at last, yes, if you are using a @Singleton, you have to inject it everywhere you want to use it. I think that's tidy and simple anyway..

Comment: Awesome Eirik. Thanks a lot. On last question. If I have a simple class like : class A{ B Obj;}. Here I want to inject Obj to A. A is a normal class. Can you please let me know what should I use in moduleloader ..confused how to use bind for this

Comment: Hi again. If you have a regular class that you do not want to run as a module nor make a singleton, and you want to initiate over and over I think the best way is to pass the Obj in the constructor.